# Simple Apache .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I basically want each request to

```
http://localhost/~lucamatteis/datadict/AccessionMainName
```

to actually call

```
http://localhost/~lucamatteis/datadict/index.php/AccessionMainName
```

Here's my current `.htaccess` physically located under `~lucamatteis/datadict/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~lucamatteis/datadict/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. I've tried **everything**. At this point I think the issue is that It's using the tilde, or I'm not sure.

In the `phpinfo()` under the loaded modules section `mod_rewrite` is loaded. I'm not sure where else to look as I might need to load an extra thing for mod_rewrite to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: A good way to debug rewrite is to turn on RewriteLog/RewriteLogLevel: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: Enable rewrite logging so you can see what's happening. Also you will need to explain what "this doesn't work" means. What does happen? If nothing at all seems to happen then please say so as there are infinite things "this doesn't work" could mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure that you're able to override Apache configuration trough .htaccess file ( `AllowOwerride` config directive).

Then try to remove `RewriteBase` directive totally. In this case the current directory will be used as base.

Comment: +1 for the advice of getting rid of RewriteBase. I think I've never needed to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Change you ReWriteBase to your physical directory:

```
/home/lucamatteis/public_html/datadict  (or something similar)
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase

Comment: Still not working. I think RewriteBase is relative to your apache root, that's why you see it being set to `/` most of the time. But anyway, not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you want to do an internal redirection to a file that does not exists:

```
/home/lucamatteis/public_html/datadict/index.php/AccessionMainName
```

This will only work if index.php is a directory and AccessionMainName is a file.

I don't think such thing can be done. Most of the times, using query string parameters is all you need:

```
index.php?AccessionMainName
```

... and you read it from `$_GET['AccessionMainName']`.